# Mysql JOIN multiple tables with latitude and longitude

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to display advertisements relevant to data of the user.
Here, data is Latitude and longitude.

`ADS` table: ad to display with ad name, ad text, **latitude and longitude**

Tables with data of the user:
`TABLE1`: user id + **latitude and longitude**,
`TABLE2`: user id + **latitude and longitude**,
`TABLE3`: user id + **latitude and longitude**,
`TABLE4`: user id + **latitude and longitude**

The purpose is to display an ad, when the latitude and longitude of the ad matches the latitude and longtitude of *one or more* lines in the 4 tables in a range of 10km and limit by 3 results.

It's working when linking one ad with one table in range of 10km, but doesn't with more tables.
 - I'm not comfortable with `OUTER JOINS` -

My query looks like this and I'm pretty sure I'm going wrong...

```
SELECT ADS.name, ADS.text, 
( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(TABLE1.latitude) ) 
 * cos( radians( ADS.latitude ) ) 
 * cos( radians( ADS.longitude ) 
 - radians(TABLE1.longitude) ) 
 + sin( radians(TABLE1.latitude) ) 
 * sin( radians( ADS.latitude ) ) ) ) 
 AS check1, 

 ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(TABLE2.latitude) ) 
 * cos( radians( ADS.latitude ) ) 
 * cos( radians( ADS.longitude ) 
 - radians(TABLE2.longitude) ) 
 + sin( radians(TABLE2.latitude) ) 
 * sin( radians( ADS.latitude ) ) ) ) 
 AS check2, 

 ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(TABLE3.latitude) ) 
 * cos( radians( ADS.latitude ) ) 
 * cos( radians( ADS.longitude ) 
 - radians(TABLE3.longitude) ) 
 + sin( radians(TABLE3.latitude) ) 
 * sin( radians( ADS.latitude ) ) ) ) 
 AS check3, 

 ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(TABLE4.latitude) ) 
 * cos( radians( ADS.latitude ) ) 
 * cos( radians( ADS.longitude ) 
 - radians(TABLE4.longitude) ) 
 + sin( radians(TABLE4.latitude) ) 
 * sin( radians( ADS.latitude ) ) ) ) 
 AS check4 

FROM ADS 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN TABLE1 
ON TABLE1.user = ? 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN TABLE2 
ON TABLE2.user = ? 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN TABLE3 
ON TABLE3.user = ? 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN TABLE4 
ON TABLE4.user = ? 
HAVING check1 < 10 OR check2 < 10 OR check3 < 10 OR check4 < 10 
LIMIT 0,3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `user` isn't unique in `TABLE1` (or any of the TABLEn), then there's a potential to return multiple copies of the same row from `ADS`.

With the query the way it is, if the specified user isn't found in TABLE4, then the query won't return any rows. I suspect what you meant was a `LEFT JOIN`, with `ADS` as the driving table, but that's just a guess. We don't know what those tables contain, why are there four of them, etc.)

If there's a reason you are using a RIGHT JOIN, and if the query with one table is working for you...

and if there is a small number of rows in each of TABLE1, TABLE2, TABLE3, TABLE4 for a specified user...

You could concatenate the results of queries of those tables into single derived table, and then join to the derived table. As an example:

```
 SELECT ADS.name, ADS.text, 
 ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(t.latitude) ) 
 * cos( radians( ADS.latitude ) ) 
 * cos( radians( ADS.longitude ) 
 - radians(t.longitude) ) 
 + sin( radians(t.latitude) ) 
 * sin( radians( ADS.latitude ) ) ) 
 )  AS check1
   FROM ADS
  RIGHT
   JOIN ( SELECT TABLE1.latitude, TABLE1.longitude
            FROM TABLE1 WHERE TABLE1.user = ?
           UNION ALL
          SELECT TABLE2.latitude, TABLE2.longitude
            FROM TABLE2 WHERE TABLE2.user = ?
           UNION ALL
          SELECT TABLE3.latitude, TABLE3.longitude
            FROM TABLE3 WHERE TABLE3.user = ?
           UNION ALL
          SELECT TABLE4.latitude, TABLE4.longitude
            FROM TABLE4 WHERE TABLE4.user = ?
        ) t
 HAVING check1 < 10
  LIMIT 3
```

Comment: Indeed I need to use LEFT JOIN. RIGHT JOIN was working on one table because there was a result on the 2nd table, but don't have to be the case. I'm trying your query

Comment: There seems to be an error; SQL query in PhpmyAdmin says *error close to HAVING check1 < 10 LIMIT 3*

Comment: @gr3g: I see a mistake I made in the inline view query, that fourth SELECT should reference `TABLE4` rather than `TABLE2`. (The query I posted is guaranteed to cause an error. You can run just the inline view query, to see the error.) Otherwise, my example query is identical to the query you posted, except for replacing the reference to `TABLE1` with an inline view. I assigned the alias `t` to the inline view, so I changed the qualifiers on the references in the `check1` expression (replacing `TABLE1.` with `t.`.

Comment: There was a `ON` missing too

Comment: @gr3g: or, you could just remove the `RIGHT` keyword, since the predicate in the HAVING clause is going to eliminate any rows that weren't matched. Adding the keyword `CROSS` doesn't change the query, but serves as documentation that there is no JOIN predicate, every row from ADS will be joined to every row from t. (As I noted in my answer, it wasn't clear why you were using a RIGHT JOIN... I kept your query exactly like it was (without the `ON` clause... the only change I made was to replace the reference to `TABLE1` with an inline view.

Answer (score 0):

This was finaly what I needed:

```
$reponse = $bdd->prepare('
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT ADS.id AS id, ADS.name, ADS.text, 
( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(t.latitude) ) 
 * cos( radians(ADS.latitude ) ) 
 * cos( radians( ADS.longitude ) 
 - radians(t.longitude) ) 
 + sin( radians(t.latitude) ) 
 * sin( radians( ADS.latitude ) ) ) ) 
 AS distance 
 FROM ADS 
RIGHT  
   JOIN ( SELECT TABLE1.latitude, TABLE1.longitude
            FROM TABLE1 WHERE TABLE1.user = :user 
           UNION ALL 
          SELECT TABLE2.latitude, TABLE2.longitude
            FROM TABLE2 WHERE TABLE2.user = :user 
           UNION ALL 
          SELECT TABLE3.latitude, TABLE3.longitude 
            FROM TABLE3 WHERE TABLE3.user = :user 
           UNION ALL 
          SELECT TABLE4.latitude, TABLE4.longitude 
            FROM TABLE4 WHERE TABLE4.user = :user 
        ) t 
        ON 1 
 HAVING distance < 10
) req GROUP BY id LIMIT 0,3
');   
$reponse->execute(array('user' => $_SESSION['id']));
```